# 参考までに、通報がどう処理されているかの解説

Tags: サポート

通報は、自分では行うことができないモデレーションが必要とされていることをコミュニティに対して周知するモデレーション行動です。通報ボタンをクリックすると、ダイアログが表示され、そこから、どのような注意喚起が必要なのかを選択することで、通報は行われます。

通報を処理するアルゴリズムはいくつかある様子で、(e.g. 低品質レビューキューに送られるなど)基本的には自動処理されていきます。自動処理できなかった通報は、モデレーターの通報キューに積まれていきます。

モデレーターは、積まれた通報キューのエントリーに対して、以下の処理を行います。

- コメント通報の場合:

  - 当該コメントを削除/編集する or 通報を破棄
- 質問/回答通報の場合:

  - (必要なら何かしら対応を行った後)「役に立つ」として終了させる
  - その通報は必要なかったと、理由と共に「却下」して終了させる

モデレーターが、通報キューからどの通報を「役に立つ」として、どの通報を「却下」するのかは、モデレーターの裁量に任されている様子ですが、参考までに、自分は以下の方針でこれを行っています。

- 何かしらの(モデレータとしての)モデレーション行動につながれば「役に立つ」、そうでなければ「却下」

一つ注意として、コメント通報は、コメントを改変ないし削除するか、その通報を破棄するかの選択肢しか存在せず、また破棄理由も付与できないので、通報しているそのコメント自体をどうこうする以外の対応が必要である場合、質問・回答に対して通報を行う方がベターです。